# How to get pid of pgpool 2 process in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I've installed Postgres 11.18 and pgpool 2 from their [Git Repo](https://github.com/pgpool/pgpool2.git).
Now I want to get the pid of the pgpool process so that I can attach that to gdb and do my debugging.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will be enough?

```
pgrep -f bin/pgpool
```